# How to choose first key of foreach() within a foreach()

Tags: php, json, foreach

I cant seem to get this working right it just returns each of value0. I only want the first key under data1 so the values of 1111 and 3333. If I add a key to value0 I get "1" as its value and the same number of them are displayed. In this example there are four and only two should return.

Json:

```
{
"json": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "data0": "123",
        "data1": [
            {
                "value0": "1111",
                "value1": "aaaa"
            },
            {
                "value0": "2222",
                "value1": "bbbb"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data0": "abc",
        "data1": [
            {
                "value0": "3333",
                "value1": "cccc"
            },
            {
                "value0": "4444",
                "value1": "dddd"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"number": 300,
"end": ""
}
```

PHP:

```
foreach( $json->data as $data) {
    foreach($data->data1 as $value) {
        echo "{$value->value0}<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($json->data as $data) echo $data->data1[0]->value0;`

Comment: I cant select this as answer but I would. I was close. I was putting the key in the wrong spot. This also cleans it up into one foreach().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want both array 0 index

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
foreach( $json['data'] as $data) {
  echo $data['data1'][0]['value0']; //11113333 
}
```

or use directly without foreach for get one value

```
echo $json['data'][0]['data1'][0]['value0']; //1111
```

Comment: Thank you I guess I will select this as answer. Its pretty much the same thing from @deceze. 0 index is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your object version, you could loop like so:

```
$jsonObj    =   json_decode($json);

foreach($jsonObj as $value) {
    foreach($value as $data => $object) {
            echo $object->data1[0]->value0;
        }
    }
```

Should give you:

```
11113333
```

Comment: This didnt work right. The second foreach() works just like the other answers but being nested in the first there are errors around it.

Comment: That's weird, when I run it there are no errors and it echoes out the values.